# Store String Array in MySql through java?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have a String Array in a java program. I am using jdbc driver to store data in MySql.

There is a reference variable "pstmt" that refers to a prepared statement

now I want to call the following method:

```
String [] items = {pen, ball, speaker, mic};  
pstmt.setArray(1, ....);
```

where "items" refer to String array but the method setArray() takes java.sql.Array instead of String array.

So how can I convert the string array "items" to a java.sql.Array so that I can pass an argument in the above method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this,

```
String [] items = {pen, ball, speaker, mic};  
pstmt.setArray(1, pstmt.getConnection().createArrayOf("String", items));
```

Comment: Are you sure this works in practice?

Answer (score 4):

Generally when you try to store an array in a RDBM it's an indication that you need further normalization of your data model. I.e. you could set up another table with a foreign-key relationship to your current table and then store each element of the array in the new table.

Comment: I liked your point but my client's requirement is to store all the records only in one table.
I know this is very bad approach to manage data.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `setArray(int i, Array x)` and `java.sql.Array` which is an interface for retrieving and materializing an SQL3 ARRAY data type can't be used in the fashion you want to use it.

By the way, implementing Array is *optional* according to the JDBC specification and I don't think MySQL's driver provide an implementation.